# bind something to property of type registered with qmlRegisterSingletonType

Tags: qt, qml

Is it possible to bind something to property of registered as singleton type? I can't find correct syntax to do something like

```
Item {
  id: rootItem
  MySingleton.anProperty: rootItem.width
}
```

(above results in: "Non-existent attached object")

MySingleton registered registered via

```
int qmlRegisterSingletonType(const char *uri, int versionMajor, int 
versionMinor, const char *typeName, QObject *(* ) ( QQmlEngine *, QJSEngine 
* ) callback)
```

Answer (score 1):

There is no `MySingleton` object or group property in the scope of `Item` and you cannot use this syntax to bind properties for external objects.

It is possible via the `Binding` element:

```
Binding {
    target: MySingleton
    property: 'anProperty'
    value: rootItem.width
}
```

Since your title and question is ambiguous, maybe what you actually want to do is as simple as:

```
Item {
  id: rootItem
  width: MySingleton.anProperty
}
```